# Wifi is very slow on ubuntu 16.10

Tags: wireless

I installed ubuntu 16.10 and my wifi is very slow. I turned off power managment and still it is very slow. Please advice.

after lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 I get :

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b2] (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260 [8086:4262]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: okay. Can you look at it now?

Comment: It looks OK. How do you measure the speed? Can you also post the output of `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: it's very long.

Comment: [ 1299.938997] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 8 is active and mapped to fifo 3 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 1299.939067] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 9 is active and mapped to fifo 7 ra_tid 0x0000 [77,77]
[ 1299.939138] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 10 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 1299.939210] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 11 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 1299.939281] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 12 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]

Comment: this is a small part of it

Comment: [ 1299.939495] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 15 is active and mapped to fifo 5 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 1299.939569] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 16 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 1299.939641] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 17 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 1299.939713] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 18 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 1299.939785] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 19 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[ 1299.939855] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 20 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]

Comment: I think @Pilot6 and I are very interested in the firmware. Please post: `dmesg | grep iwl | grep firm` We hope it is -17.

Comment: [ 1404.648122] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 17.352738.0
[ 1527.785823] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 17.352738.0
[ 1541.866472] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 17.352738.0
[ 1557.226716] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 17.352738.0
[ 1569.514629] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 17.352738.0
[ 1587.435311] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 17.352738.0
[ 1606.123844] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 17.352738.0

Comment: Please do not post this to comments. Post it to your question.